# modulus operator in C#

Tags: c#

Which function we can use to find modulus of floating point value ?

Answer (score 1):

Theres probably a function somewhere but the following is equivalent and simple enough:

```
a - b*(Math.Floor(a/b))
```

for `a % b`

`math.h` in old C has the function `fmod`.  would c# even allow you to  to use it?  i dont know either way.

PS - are you sure the `%` operator doesnt work?

Answer (score 1):

Float/double are **never exact values**, therefore `%` operator will not work consistently. Use [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28VS.80%29.aspx) instead to make modulus operator work on real numbers.

```
 decimal a, b c;
 a = 32.3M;
 b = 3.23M;

 c = a % b; //c should be zero.
```

**EDIT**

Check [Avoid modulus operator with types float and double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) section (**Bottom of the page**) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem with using the standard modulo operator % ?

```
double c = a%b;
```

Comment: Yes, there is: `Line 4: error: invalid operands of types 'double' and 'double' to binary 'operator%'`

Comment: MSDN disagrees - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx I'm also pretty sure I've used this before in C# many, many times with doubles.

Comment: My apologies, I misread the tag and thought this was a C++ question.

Answer (score 0):

```
   float x = 5.1F;
   float y = 2.3F;
   float  t = x % y;
```